# Prior to a month

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, vocabulary, formal-language

I would like to ask if the following sentence is correct:

> "This certificate should be renewed prior to a month from its expiration date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasing suggested is not commonly used and when I first read "prior to a month from" it said to me "at" or "on".  However, reading it properly, it reads worse.  It actually implies that you have a month from expiry to renew the certificate because breaking that part of the sentence up you get

[Prior to] [a month From....]

In other words

> This certificate should be renewed **within a month after** its expiration date

To alter it to convey what I believe you wish to say, you could change it to

> This certificate should be renewed at least one month prior to the expiration date.